# insert document into multiple instance of couch DB in Node JS with all success and failure result in any way possible

Tags: node.js, promise, couchdb, async.js, couchdb-nano

i have array of db like

```
const dbArr = ["http://localhost:5984", "http://xyz_couchdb.com:5984"]
```

data to insert

```
let data ={
            _id: 324567,
            name: Harry,
            gerder: male
        }
```

here is the logic i am using nano module

```
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            let res = [];
            let rej = [];
            let counter = 0;

            for(let i = 0; i < dbArr.length ; i++){
                dbArr[i].insert(data, (err, body) => {
                    err ? rej.push(err) : res.push(body)
                    if(counter === obj.dbArray.length -1){
                        rej.length ? reject(rej) : resolve(res)
                    }
                    counter++;
                })
            }
        })
```

what can be the best possible way to achieve this using promise or async module or anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, we gotta use `Array.map` to create one `promise` for each element of `dbArr`, then we gotta wait all `promises` to end using Promise.all. The `catch` is here so we handle the errors.

```
function getAll(dbArr) {
  return Promise.all(dbArr.map(x => x.insert(data)));
}

getAll(dbArr)
  .then((rets) => {
    // Handle the returns
    // They are in an array
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle the error
  });
```

---

**EDIT** :

Ok after checking out the documentation of [node-couchdb](http://node-couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage) (the one I suppose you use) - I saw that the `.insert()` method do not return a `Promise` but only a callback.

So we gotta transform the method, so it will return a Promise using `util.Promisify()`

```
const {
   promisify,
} = require('util');

function getAll(dbArr) {
  return Promise.all(dbArr.map(x => promisify(x.insert)(data)));
}

getAll(dbArr)
  .then((rets) => {
    // Handle the returns
    // They are in an array
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle the error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i am not getting the actual callback data inside the success array of promise.all.. actual callback data on successful insertion is { ok: true,
  id: '324567',
  rev: '1-7e8fb36ba459c88099d63e9938f8bcc3' } but i am getting something like

Comment: {
            "uri": {
                "protocol": "http:",
                "slashes": true,
                "auth": null,
                "host": "localhost:5984",
                "port": "5984",
                "hostname": "localhost",
                "hash": null,
                "search": null,
                "query": null,
                "pathname": "/harry",
                "path": "/harry",
                "href": "http://localhost:5984/harry"
            }

Comment: ,
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "accept": "application/json",
                "host": "localhost:5984",
                "content-length": 65
            }
        }

Comment: @xExplorer I've edited my post, it seems that the librairie you use do not support natively `Promises`